# App level messages not visible in Google App engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using Python on Google app engine. I am logging both errors and info level messages. As per documentation, I should see messages in Google App engine logs, however there are no messages visible. My code below and Log output is below. Please point out, why I am not seeing messages in Google app engine logs. The code is a sample Photohunt service and I am trying to modify it.

My code:

```
def post(self):
"""Exposed as `POST /api/photos`.

Takes the following payload in the request body.  Payload represents a
Photo that should be created.
{
  'id':0,
  'ownerUserId':0,
  'ownerDisplayName':'',
  'ownerProfileUrl':'',
  'ownerProfilePhoto':'',
  'themeId':0,
  'themeDisplayName':'',
  'numVotes':0,
  'voted':false, // Whether or not the current user has voted on this.
  'created':0,
  'fullsizeUrl':'',
  'thumbnailUrl':'',
  'voteCtaUrl':'', // URL for Vote interactive post button.
  'photoContentUrl':'' // URL for Google crawler to hit to get info.
}

Returns the following JSON response representing the created Photo.
{
  'id':0,
  'ownerUserId':0,
  'ownerDisplayName':'',
  'ownerProfileUrl':'',
  'ownerProfilePhoto':'',
  'themeId':0,
  'themeDisplayName':'',
  'numVotes':0,
  'voted':false, // Whether or not the current user has voted on this.
  'created':0,
  'fullsizeUrl':'',
  'thumbnailUrl':'',
  'voteCtaUrl':'', // URL for Vote interactive post button.
  'photoContentUrl':'' // URL for Google crawler to hit to get info.
}


Issues the following errors along with corresponding HTTP response codes:
400: 'Bad Request' if the request is missing image data.
401: 'Unauthorized request' (if certain parameters are present in the
     request)
401: 'Access token expired' (there is a logged in user, but he doesn't
     have a refresh token and his access token is expiring in less than
     100 seconds, get a new token and retry)
500: 'Error while writing app activity: ' + error from client library.
"""
try:
 user = self.get_user_from_session()
 current_theme = model.Theme.get_current_theme()
 //mthemeId = self.request.get('themeId')   
 console.log("Check not working or working. Please work")   
 logger.debug("Writing photo x" )
 mthemeId = self.request.get('themeId')
 logging.info("Error while writing app activity: %s", mthemeId)

 logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
 logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

 logging.debug("Debug info "+mthemeId)
current_theme = self.request.get('themeId')
current_theme = model.Theme.all().filter('theme_id =', long(mthemeId))
  if current_theme:
    uploads = self.get_uploads('image')
    blob_info = uploads[0]
    photo = model.Photo(owner_user_id=user.key().id(),
        owner_display_name=user.google_display_name,
        owner_profile_photo=user.google_public_profile_photo_url,
        owner_profile_url=user.google_public_profile_url,
        theme_id=current_theme.key().id(),
        theme_display_name=current_theme.display_name,
        created=datetime.datetime.now(),
        num_votes=0,
        image_blob_key=blob_info.key())
    photo.put()
    try:
      result = self.add_photo_to_google_plus_activity(user, photo,mthemeId)
    except apiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
      logging.error("Error while writing app activity: %s", str(e))
    self.send_success(photo)
  else:
logging.error("Error while writing app activity: %s", mthemeId)
    self.send_error(404, "Current theme not there")
except UserNotAuthorizedException as e:
  self.send_error(401, e.msg)
```

Log
    2014-06-06 20:17:04.620 /api/photos 404 21ms 0kb PhotoHunt Agent module=default version=1
    0.1.0.30 - - [06/Jun/2014:07:47:04 -0700] "POST /api/photos HTTP/1.1" 404 102 - "PhotoHunt Agent" "my-moments.appspot.com" 
    ms=21 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000011 app_engine_release=1.9.5 instance=00c61b117cfb67f2ae092dbf7270939f50631e97
    I 2014-06-06 20:17:04.610
    make: Got type 
    I 2014-06-06 20:17:04.611
    validate: Got type

There are no messages from the Post which were scripted using Logging.debug or Logging.error? How can I see these messages. The documentation says that they should be available in Logs but I do not see any. Any help/pointers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What is being logged is a 404 for `/api/photos`, so your url mapping for that url is not correct or missing.

Also, you will be getting 500 errors with this code.  `console.log("Check not working or working. Please work")` is javascript syntax, not Python.  `logger.debug("Writing photo x" )` will throw an exception, because you haven't declared `logger` yet.  That should be `logging.debug`.

And, make sure you have `import logging`

Comment: Thanks for pointer. The code is little jumbled up as I tried every possible approach. I removed Logger for now and also illogical console. The 404 error is because of logical issue there, that it is looking for a current theme which it is unable to get. I have removed the condition for now and log output is as follows without 404. However, it still does not show me logs. Logging import is included.                                         /api/photos 200 1966ms 0kb PhotoHunt Agent module=default version=1

Comment: Remove the try/except, and see where it is erring.

Comment: If it is posting correctly, then it is an exception in `self.send_success` or `self.send_error`.  Remove the try/except, and check the error in the log